# how to enable InAppWebView full screen while using fragmentation in flutter mobile App?

Tags: webview, fullscreen, flutter-inappwebview

This is my code what should I do to make full screen.

1. I want to make full screen to In-App-Web-View for open local html Page from device.
2. I have tried many package make InAppWebView full screen like flutter-fullscreen and any more.

```
InAppWebView(
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          controller.setOptions(
              options: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
            crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.MOBILE,
              allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true,
              allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true,
              useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
              javaScriptEnabled: true,
            ),
          ));

          controller.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(argument['htmlFilePath'])));
        },
```